# Prevent screen reader from reading the whole page

Tags: javascript, html, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I have an HTML page that has a lot of content. When I open it with a screen reader (specifically, JAWS) without doing anything but entering the URL, the screen reader starts to read all of the content on the site. The reader stops if I interrupt it, or if it reaches the end of the page. How can I prevent it from doing so, and make sure that it will read content only after interaction with the user (e.g. pressing arrow keys or <kbd>Tab</kbd>, clicking the mouse, ...) rather than automatically?

(I do not want to use `aria-hidden`, because I want the elements to be visible for the reader.)

Details:
Browser: IE8, IE9 and Firefox v34
JAWS: V15.0

The page has one `div` that has the `aria-live` attribute, but it is only for one title, not for the whole page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an HTML page issue. That's what JAWS almost always does with HTML pages. For example, when I went to stackoverflow.com just now, JAWS said:

> page has 100 headings and 768 links //began reading the page

Don't worry about it. It's not related to your page. Besides, it only takes a control key to stop it.